# Need Jenkins job to grab screenshot, only works when JNLP launched from browser, not as a service

Tags: jenkins, jnlp

So I'm trying to use `pyautogui` to make the mouse click on a button after finding it using an image of it.
The library uses `ImageGrab.grab()` internally to grab a screenshot.
The code is run on a Jenkins slave which is a Windows laptop.

Everything works fine when I download the `.jnlp` file and launch it with just double click,
but when I run it as a Windows service after installing it using `javaws slave-agent.jnlp` -> File -> Install as a service, I get this exception: `OSError: screen grab failed` which I assume has to do with permissions?

Answer (score 0):

The Service does not have permissions to control your screen. So the best way is to start a Batch script on startup which starts your jnlp session.
So you can download the jnlp via script and execute it so that your session has full permissions to control the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have created service using Administrator user.
If a service is created like this, then it should have all the permissions.
Another way is check running your agent from command line (again open cmd in admin mode) and check the results.

Update me with the status, please.

Comment: Didn't work - I deleted the service (`sc delete {service name}`), launched cmd as admin and installed the service (`javaws slave-agent.jnlp`)

Comment: We're you logged in as a system administrator?

Comment: Also the way you have installed the service is not correct. Launch slave (launch from browser) , Click on file -> install as a service. If it is successful then done. If it gives you access denied error, then do these steps. Stop the web agent window. Go to slave's workspace. You will find jenkins-slave.exe. Open command prompt at this location in admin mode. Run command, (jenkins-slave.exe install). This should properly install your service. Update me with the result.